How to change the font of a specific math mode letter for the entire document
In a certain document I have I'd prefer to have a different font for the v in math mode. I am using the v to represent molar volume and the usual font for v in LaTeX I prefer to use it for velocity. In this precise document I don't talk about velocity and I would like to change the font from the usual to a v that looks like this

I am working with Overleaf and an MWE for this would simply be
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

Here is how my v appears in Latex's math mode

\begin{equation}
    v
\end{equation}

To reiterate my point, here is another $v$ in math mode

And, once again...
$$v$$

\end{document}



please provide a minimal example which shows how you produce your v in maths mode at the moment. right now we don't know the format, engine or configuration you're using, so nobody can tell you what to change.

@cfr Just updated it. I'm sorry for causing inconveniences.

Note that this glyph shape is similar to a Greek small letter nu, but this might not be an issue here.

Changing the font per lettter is possible if a little strange, but rather than make people guess, which font you intend how did you generate that image, the pdf or tex source of that would say exactly which font you intend.

you can always use \mathcal{v} or \mathscr{v} for another symbol for v

Use the “v” from Times.
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\DeclareSymbolFont{molarvolume}{OT1}{ptm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{molarvolume}{`v}

\begin{document}

Here is how my v appears in \LaTeX's math mode $v$.

Of course, readers might interpret it as $\nu$.

\end{document}

Now that you see the output, you can just remove the two lines in the preamble and use a standard “v”. Your readers will be thankful.

By the way, using $$ in a LaTeX document has always been deprecated.
